# Python Separating String into Words and Recursion

Tags: python, string, recursion

I'm trying to create a code that will take in an input (example below)

> Input:
>   BHK158 VEHICLE 11
>   OIUGHH MOTORCYCLE 34.46
>   BHK158 VEHICLE 12.000
>   TRIR TRUCK 2.0
>   BLAS215 MOTORCYCLE 0.001
>   END

and produce an output where each license plate number is listed and the total cost is listed beside (example below)

> Corresponding output:
>   OIUGHH: 5.8582
>   BHK158: 5.75
>   TRIR: 2.666
>   BLAS215: 0.00017

The vehicle license plates are charged $0.25 per kilometer (the kilometers are the number values in the input list), trucks are charged $1.333 per kilometer, and motorcycles $0.17 per kilometer. The output is listed in descending order.

Here is my code thus far:

```
fileinput = input('Input: \n')
split_by_space = fileinput.split(' ')

vehicles = {}


    if split_by_space[1] == 'VEHICLE':
        split_by_space[2] = (float(split_by_space[2]) * 0.25) 
    elif split_by_space[1] == 'TRUCK':
        split_by_space[2] = float(split_by_space[2]) * 1.333 
    elif split_by_space[1] == 'MOTORCYCLE':
        split_by_space[2] = float(split_by_space[2]) * 0.17 

    if split_by_space[0] in vehicles:
        previousAmount = vehicles[split_by_space[0]]
        vehicles[split_by_space[0]] = previousAmount + split_by_space[2]
    else:
        vehicles[split_by_space[0]] = split_by_space[2]
```

Thanks, any help/hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code throws an IndentationError, please fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going through your code I noticed a few things, list indicies in python start at 0, not 1 so you were get a bunch of out of bounds errors. Secondly, input only takes the first line of the input so it was never going past the first line. `.split()` splits text by `\n` by default, you have to specify if you want to split by something else, like a space.

#### test.txt contents:

```
BHK158 VEHICLE 11
OIUGHH MOTORCYCLE 34.46
BHK158 VEHICLE 12.000
TRIR TRUCK 2.0
BLAS215 MOTORCYCLE 0.001
```

#### python code:

```
fileinput = open('test.txt', 'r')
lines = fileinput.readlines()

vehicles = {}

for line in lines:
    split_by_space = line.split(' ')
    if split_by_space[1] == "VEHICLE":
        split_by_space[2] = (float(split_by_space[2]) * 0.25)
    elif split_by_space[1] == "TRUCK":
        split_by_space[2] = float(split_by_space[2]) * 1.333
    elif split_by_space[1] == "MOTORCYCLE":
        split_by_space[2] = float(split_by_space[2]) * 0.17


    if split_by_space[0] in vehicles:
        previousAmount = vehicles[split_by_space[0]]
        vehicles[split_by_space[0]] = previousAmount + split_by_space[2]
    else:
        vehicles[split_by_space[0]] = split_by_space[2]
```

#### output:

```
{'BLAS215': 0.00017, 'OIUGHH': 5.858200000000001, 'TRIR': 2.666, 'BHK158': 5.75}
```